# Understanding Android Stacktrace

Tags: android, react-native, stack-trace

I have built an cross platform app using React Native, and have discovered a bug on the Android version of the application.  It only occurs in Android, not iOS, and it occurs when trying to use the navigation.navigate() feature of react navigation.  All I have to go off of is the stack trace, but I don't understand how to interpret it.

This is the stack trace:

```
    pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.nothing.nothingapp <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000039fe88  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::GLFunctorDrawable::onDraw(SkCanvas*)+984)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 000000000070d684  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkGpuDevice::drawDrawable(SkDrawable*, SkMatrix const*, SkCanvas*)+300)
  #00  pc 00000000003590d0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1252)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 0000000000359124  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1336)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 0000000000359124  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1336)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 0000000000359124  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1336)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 0000000000359124  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1336)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 0000000000359124  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1336)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 0000000000359124  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1336)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 00000000003590fc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1296)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000004410f0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+88)
  #00  pc 00000000003590fc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1296)
  #00  pc 000000000035a1c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*) const+200)
  #00  pc 00000000003a59a8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaPipeline::renderLayersImpl(android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue const&, bool)+688)
  #00  pc 00000000003a7110  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaPipeline::renderFrame(android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue const&, SkRect const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode> > > const&, bool, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, sk_sp<SkSurface>, SkMatrix const&)+124)
  #00  pc 00000000003a45b4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::draw(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, SkRect const&, SkRect const&, android::uirenderer::LightGeometry const&, android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue*, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, bool, android::uirenderer::LightInfo const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode> > > const&, android::uirenderer::FrameInfoVisualizer*)+416)
  #00  pc 00000000003ad224  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+1080)
  #00  pc 00000000003af460  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+524)
  #00  pc 000000000039d928  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+208)
  #00  pc 00000000003bfb44  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+88)
  #00  pc 000000000001553c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+320)
  #00  pc 0000000000014db0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+408)
  #00  pc 00000000000b61f4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #00  pc 0000000000050e24  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

Comment: Did you figure out cause and solution of this error?

Answer (score 0):

When you go in the stack trace in the android studio the errors will be shown in the red line and it will have some error code and name with the line number on which the error is. So you can search about that error or go to that line and find out what is causing the error.
In your case, I think the error is in rendering layers or frame